# DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged does not fire when selecting index in C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to select the index in DropDownList in C# code behind but the SelectedIndexChanged event does not fire. What is the right way to do it?

```
  DropDownListChapterTitles.SelectedIndex = 1;


  protected void DropDownListChapterTitles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { }
```

Comment: it doesnt fire because you are setting it yourself. try using autopostback = true in your dropdownlist, the selectedindexchanged event will fire then

Comment: autopostback is set to true. I need to fire it from codebehid.

Comment: You shouldn't try to invoke an event from code...not a good way to write code. Rather extract whatever you've written in the event into a method (which accepts arguments if necessary) and do the job in that method. Use that method in the future. Sometimes its really hard to say why exactly is this code running - was it because of that event or was it because I triggered it...hence thats why...

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownListChapterTitles.SelectedIndex = 1;
// Call it yourself
DropDownListChapterTitles_SelectedIndexChanged(this, null);
```

Comment: "this" means current class. useless for you probably.

Comment: I don't need the Args. But if I call it from GridView.SelectIndexChanged then what will this be pointing to?

Comment: DropDownListChapterTitles_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null); 
use it like that if you want, so it won't confuse you.

Comment: Ok this far it is ok. However, does it not violate the rules of event handling?

Answer (score 0):

Check your markup it should look like this

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListChapterTitles" AutoPostBack="True"
     OnSelectedIndexChange="DropDownListChapterTitles_SelectedIndexChanged">

</asp:DropDownList>
```

I added `OnSelectedIndexChange="DropDownListChapterTitles_SelectedIndexChanged"`